# How to hide application from list of installed application in android

Tags: android

I have listed installed applications.I want to hide the selected app in my mobile.

Some application are used launcher to hide the application from the launcher.I want to hide the application from the mobile.

Any chances to hide the application from mobile without using launcher?

Comment: Looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664510/8244632)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to hide application icon from list of application.

Hide app's icon using below code:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Here is how to bring back the app's icon.

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: already i try this code..these hide our app..But i want to hide the third party app..