# Android hide app icon from menu

Tags: android, menu, icons, hide

I need to hide my icon application  from menu, I have tried this

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(Test.this,com.example.MainActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

but it doesn't work...how can i do it?

Comment: "but it doesn't work... ",  which problem are you facing?

Comment: The icon is enabled anyway?
Try link. It should help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114439/android-hide-unhide-app-icon-programmatically
Note that the icon may not be gone until the next reboot.

Comment: Not work...The icon not disappear from menu!

Comment: Reboot your device after running the above code. There is no requirement for a home screen implementation to necessarily detect this change on the fly.

Comment: I have read that this features has been removed from kitkat, but for example in cerberus app it works

Answer (score -1):

You have made a mistake in the syntax. Change it as given below:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.example","com.example.MainActivity");
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

It will work like a charm!!