# Android hide app icon programatically

Tags: android

I have been trying to hide my app's icon from the app drawer and open it from dialler. The dialler part works perfertly, but i am having issues with hiding it. My problem is, if i hide my activity, it's get destroyed and i can no longer access it from my dialler. I have tried creating a duplicate activity as suggested  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114439/android-hide-unhide-app-icon-programmatically), but if i do that then my initial problem of hiding the icon is not solved.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And **why** would you kike to do so?

Comment: @DerGolem It could be an app designed to run mainly in background, which the user would like to hide from his app drawer. Just to keep things clean.

Comment: In fact, I happen to have such an app installed, however it needs root access.

Comment: @Ealhad I want to do it dynamically only if the user decides to hide it. Here is the code is used to hide the app ' private void hideMainActivity() {
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, LauncherActivity.class);
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                componentName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        );
    }'

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it wrong. Just set the MainActivity as the launcher and set a duplicate activity in the dialler.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.

PackageManager pkg=this.getPackageManager();
pkg.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this,SplashActivity.class),PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);