# Hide Android App From Launcher

Tags: android, manifest, apktool

I'm trying to modify APK, I want to hide it from home screen but it should be openable

This is some part of manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I have already tried to replace `LAUNCHER` with `DEFAULT` but then I can't open the app, I want to open it one time only, can someone help me? Sorry for my bad English, I hope u will understand what I mean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114439/android-hide-unhide-app-icon-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android hide/unhide app icon programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114439/android-hide-unhide-app-icon-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in several treads in the past.
You can do it programmatic by adding the below code:

Hide :

`PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
 ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class); 
 pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);`

Unhide:

`PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class);
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);`