# AOSP 11 How to hide the system app icon in home/launcher

Tags: android, android-source

AOSP11、Android11，I have the source code of the system，I want to hide the system app icon, such as Settings, when I remove the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in AndroidManifest.xml of Settings, but it didn't take effect.Is there any other way？

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114439/android-hide-unhide-app-icon-programmatically